# how to enable fsockopen function in php

Tags: php

i want to enable fsockopen()

i checked my php.ini  there i changed

```
allow_url_fopen = On
```

but still am unable to use fsockopen()
i checked it with small php code

```
if(!function_exists("fsockopen")) {
 echo "Function Exists";
 }
 else
 echo "function not exists";
```

Result

> function not exists

Answer (score 5):

Your if() logic is flawed in that example, you are echoing "function not exists" when function_exists returns true.

Comment: Are you saying that the example was wrong, or that the problem is resolved now?  If the issue is resolved please mark this correct so it won't show up under Unanswered questions.